Weird values for http.server.active_requests metric in .NET 8
I have ASP .NET Core 8 app. The app is hosted in Azure.
I collect built-in metrics https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/built-in-metrics-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-8.0 using OpenTelemetry.
My question is about http.server.active_requests metric.
When the app is up and there is no active requests, the metric looks like this:

If there is active requests, the metric looks like this:

So, every minute at the same time it writes 2 items for the http.server.active_requests metric with some weird values. I noticed that the items differ in tags: one item contains schema:https, another contains schema:http.
If I group the metrics by name, timestamp and sum the value, it looks I get a correct number. On the screenshot above -42 + 44 = 2 that is exactly the number of requests it was then.
My question is why it doesn't write the current value, but writes +/- weird values instead?

In current implementation I have to group and sum the metrics if I want to show on the chart number of active requests. What is the benefit of having the metric in the format it currently exists in?

It seems that you are executing a custom query in Logs Analytic and the value for the requests seems to represent how many requests were completed or closed how many requests were opened or initiated. Could you please share the query? Please correct me if I'm completely wrong.

Here is my KQL query:
customMetrics
| order by timestamp desc
| where name == "http.server.active_requests"

May I know more about your custom Metrics? Did you add any custom metric into your.net 8 application? If yes, could you share them in the question?

Here is the app: https://github.com/verdysh/Metrics
I couldn't reproduce this behavior when I run the app on my local machine. On my local machine it works as expected. But it's reproduced constantly if I deploy the app to Azure. In Azure the app's run on Linux, on my local machine I have Windows. Here is a screenshot of Azure's instance ApplicationInsight logs: https://ibb.co/R21ntZH . Here is a screenshot of Azure's instance app's console: https://ibb.co/5L4XQ3D

PS. If you are going to run the app please note the following. (1) You need to put AppInsights connection string into settings (appsettings.Development.json for local run; Environment variables in Azure for running the app in Azure); (2) I added my custom console logger which I copied from default implementation, removed some internal code and hardcoded filter for showing http.server.active_requests metric only).
